# The predict() function is throwing an error even though model columns and data are identical

Tags: r, xgboost, predict, mlr

I currently have a model already trained and saved in MLR. I am trying to produce predictions on new data but it is not working properly and throwing this error:

> Error in predict.xgb.Booster(m, newdata = data.matrix(.newdata), ...)
> :    Feature names stored in object and newdata are different!

However, the columns in the new data and MLR model object are identical and in the same order as:

`mod$features %>% setdiff(task %>% getTaskFeatureNames())`
outputs `character(0)`

and
`mod$features==(task %>% getTaskFeatureNames())`
outputs a vector of all `TRUE`.

Comment: Can you edit the question to include the output of names(new) and names(orig) where 'new' and 'orig' are the two dataframes?

Comment: I can't post the output because there are too many variables but they are identical, in the same order, and have the same data type.

Comment: Here's the predicate that throws this error when TRUE: !identical(object[["feature_names"]], colnames(newdata)))

Comment: Are you doing feature selection?